# Set origin point for Entity rotation (Qt 3D)

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I have a simple 3D scene and a box that I want to rotate around its origin point:

```
Entity {
    components: [ mesh, phongMaterial, transform ]

    CuboidMesh {
        id: mesh
        yzMeshResolution: Qt.size(2, 2)
        xzMeshResolution: Qt.size(2, 2)
        xyMeshResolution: Qt.size(2, 2)
        zExtent: 1
        xExtent: 1
        yExtent: 2
    }

    PhongAlphaMaterial {
        id: phongMaterial
        property color randColor: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)

        ambient: randColor
        diffuse: randColor
        specular: randColor
        shininess: 1.0
        alpha: 0.4
    }

    Transform {
        id: transform
        property real userAngle: 0.0
        scale: 1
        rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 1), userAngle)
        translation: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    QQ2.NumberAnimation {
        target: transform
        property: "userAngle"
        duration: 2000
        loops: QQ2.Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        easing.type: QQ2.Easing.InOutQuad
        from: 0
        to: 360
    }
}
```

[image]

By default the origin point is in the center of the box. I need to move the origin point down as shown on the image:

[image]

But I have no clue how to do that. I've tried to play with `Transform.translation` but that just move the shape along the axis. I've tried to play with [Transform.rotateAround(point, real angle, vector3d axis)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-transform.html#rotateAround-method) but I see no changes. I've changed the `point` value but the origin point remains in the center of the shape.

```
Transform {
    id: transform
    property real userAngle: 0.0
    matrix: rotateAround(Qt.point(1,1), userAngle, Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found a solution. The first parameter of the `rotateAround` is 3d vector, not point. So using

```
matrix: rotateAround(Qt.vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), userAngle, Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ))
```

does the trick.